# overlap divs with relative positioning?

Tags: css, html, overlap

Is it possible to overlap divs with CSS without using absolute coordinates -- that is, with relative positioning?

I have a background image I split into 3 vertical pieces,

- 1st one is left-aligned,
- 2nd one repeats across the middle,
- 3rd one is right-aligned

Then I want to have my main site content on top of that, centered.  I'm not sure how to do this without using absolute positioning.

```
      Kinda like this

|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|----------------------|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|                      |&&&&&|
|$$$$$|                      |&&&&&|
|$$$$$|shakeyour<body></body>|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|                      |&&&&&|
|$$$$$|                      |&&&&&|
|$$$$$|----------------------|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|

      Different symbols = differnt background image or pattern
```

I was thinking about having the backgrounds just as three divs, and then have the body div positioned absolutely, but I want it to be centered for widescreen displays.  Any ideas?

```
For example, the expected behavior under resizing:

|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$|--------------------------|&&&|
|$$$|                          |&&&|
|$$$|                          |&&&|
|$$$|  shakeyour<body></body>  |&&&|
|$$$|                          |&&&|
|$$$|                          |&&&|
|$$$|--------------------------|&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|

---  

|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$|------------------------------|&|
|$|                              |&|
|$|                              |&|
|$|   shakeyour<body></body>     |&|
|$|                              |&|
|$|                              |&|
|$|------------------------------|&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
|$$$$$|**********************|&&&&&|
```

Comment: I just have to complement you on the excellent ascii art.

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
   padding: 50px 20px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float: left; width: 20%;">Left</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 60%; margin: 0 20%;">Center</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 20%;">Right</div>
```

You need something like this. Of course, move styles in CSS file, and add your backgrounds.

Comment: And if u don't want it 100% of screen, put a <div> around all three of the <div>'s in my above answer, and put whatever size u want + style="margin: auto;"

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! no worries about typos from your blackberry dude it's all good.  Check out what I changed so you can see what I expect as behavior under resizing

Comment: to have main body centered, is a little tricky across browsers. I will chk when i get home